# Python: Use Function to Create New String Column in Dataframe Using Multiple Elif Statements

Tags: python, string, function, if-statement, dataframe

Background: I have a Python dataframe

Goal: I am trying to create a new string column based on values in a series of existing columns.  This requires multiple 'elif' statements.

Below is my (sample) code which is erroring out:

```
def rationale(row):
    if row['Recommendation No. 1'] == 'Category_A':
        result = []
        result.append(row['First_Flag'])
        result.append(row['Second_Flag'])
        result.append(row['Third_Flag'])
        result = ' '.join(result)
        return result
    elif row['Recommendation No. 1'] == 'Category_B':
        result.append(row['Fourth_Flag'])
        result.append(row['Fifth_Flag'])
        result.append(row['Sixth_Flag'])
        result.append(row['Seventh_Flag'])
        result = ' '.join(result)
        return result
    elif row['Recommendation No. 1'] == 'Category_C':
        result.append(row['Eigth_Flag'])
        result.append(row['Ninth_Flag'])
        result.append(row['Tenth_Flag'])
        result.append(row['Eleventh_Flag'])
        result = ' '.join(result)
        return result
    else:
        return np.nan 

df_top3_rationale['Recommendation No. 1 Rationale'] = df_top3_rationale.apply(rationale, axis=1)
```

This is the error I get on the 'elif' statements:

```
UnboundLocalError: ("local variable 'result' referenced before assignment", 'occurred at index 14854')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You only create `result` in the `if` block - where is it supposed to have come from in the `elif` blocks?

Comment: are you saying I should remove return result from all elif blocks (and leave it in the if block)?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't know precisely what you're expecting to happen, I'm just encouraging you to think about how this could possibly work. Where *are* you expecting `result` to come from `if row['Recommendation No. 1'] != 'Category_A'`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define `result` only inside the first `if` block, so if the `elif` statements execute, they do not have access to a variable named `result`, which is why the error says that the variable `result` is referenced before assignment (assignment is in this line: `result = []`). What you should do is either put the line `result = []` before the conditionals, or include it in every `if` and `elif` block.